# Selecting specific <option> tags in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors, cheerio

I want to select every `<option>` tag below the first one, and I only want the text between the value and `</option>`. I've tried to do the following;

```
$('#attributesize-size_uswomen > option')
```

However it gives me the first `<option>` only. I want to exclude the first `<option>` tag and get the values. This is the block of HTML I want it from.

I would like to obtain the 'source' sizes, i.e. 6, 6.5, etc. Thanks

```html
<select name="size_attribute[size]" id="attributesize-size_uswomen" class="size-attribute-select">
  <option>Choose Your Size</option>
  <option value="12773" source="16004">5.5</option>
  <option value="12774" source="16006">6</option>
  <option value="12775" source="16008">6.5</option>
  <option value="14805" source="16010">7</option>
  <option value="14809" source="16012">7.5</option>
  <option value="12749" source="16014">8</option>
  <option value="14816" source="16016">8.5</option>
  <option value="14820" source="16018">9</option>
  <option value="14824" source="16020">9.5</option>
  <option value="15175" source="16022">10</option>
  <option value="15178" source="16024">10.5</option>
  <option value="15184" source="16028">11.5</option>
  <option value="15187" source="16030">12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That jQuery object will contain every `option` element in that `select`. It depends on what method you call on that object as to how many of those `option` elements are used by that method - that's the code we need to see.

Comment: Did you try: `$('#attributesize-size_uswomen > option:not(:first)')`?

Answer (score 1):

As @freedomn-m suggested you can use this:

```js
$('#attributesize-size_uswomen > option:not(:first)').map(function() {
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

to get array of values from all options, except the first one. But better selector is this:

```js
'#attributesize-size_uswomen > option[value]'
```

that will work when you use empty option or not. (it will get all options that have the value attribute).